# Share a file on a PC without letting the owner know the file is being shared

Tags: windows, network-shares

Is there a way to share a file on a network and prevent the the file owner noticing that the folder is shared?

I want to hide the fact it is being shared on the network by not showing "state : shared" in the details pane in bottom of Windows Explorer and not having the shared overlay icon on its folder (the hand in Windows XP and icon of two people in Windows 7).

Comment: Let me get this straight - It's very important to you that you can access someone else's file across the network, without them knowing what you are doing, when you are doing it, or what you are going to do with the contents of that file?

Comment: @super_sonic  That was kind of my first reaction as well.  But sometimes there are rare cases where it could be legitimate... but I'm hard pressed (even with employer-approved snooping) to come up with any.

Comment: Please provide clarification to your question.

Comment: -1 just because of ethical reasons

Answer (score 1):

If the files sit remotely on a Windows-based system, just gain access (add your account to the local admins group on these systems) and mount the C$, D$, etc. drive locally on your system.  As long as the firewall on the remote systems has file-sharing open, nothing will appear different to the users, and you will have access to all.

Answer (score 0):

The premise seems a little on the unscrupulous side, but I'll take a crack at it anyway.

Since windows filesharing is so in-built, maybe using windows filesharing is the wrong solution.

That said, it would then require some other filesharing tool like NFS, FTP, Dropbox with the icon hidden, or something else.

But again, I have to say this seems like it is for an unscrupulous purpose.

Comment: I agree. Respect her privacy.

Comment: Considering the fact that he is referring to 3 separate users on the same LAN I would assume that he is either their employer or acting on their employers behalf. I'll admit it does sound a bit _sketchy_ without any context but you shouldn't jump to any conclusions.

Comment: @JustinBuser I think the "two people" he's talking about is a description of the "shared" icon, not two actual people.  And whether it is a employer sanctioned snooping or not, it still seems a little creepy.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have the passwords to their accounts then all of the files in their Users directory are easily accessible over the network. Just type in 2 backslashes \\ then the name of their computer on the network. I.E if their computer name was Frank, then type \\Frank into your windows explorer address bar, it would work from run command in your start menu as well. Otherwise right click on the file you want to share and then add read write permissions for guest. The file would then be accessible via the network.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have their user and passwords but how to access Users directory? I'm using work group not domanin

Comment: @SamanSoltani - Switch to a domain group.

Comment: @Ramhound Why even bother commenting? I can appreciate sarcasm but if you can't come up with anything better then you should wait till you think of something.

Comment: @Saman Soltani 

Run this from a dos prompt: 
`net show`

That shows you the machines visible on the network, then :
`net show SOMEMACHINE`

Will list the available shares on the Computer names SOMEMACHINE. If you don't see those hosts in Windows Explorer then try hitting `Windows-Key + r` (opens a run dialog) and then type in `\\SOMEMACHINE` and hit enter, that should open a Network Window showing the shares from that machine.